# Reusable command in a class file [without any package]

Tags: macros

I am creating my own class and in it I want to create a command that can be used as many times as you want without the previous content being replaced. This is my MWE

```
\documentclass{letter}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{mypagestyle}{
    \cleardoublepage
    \thispagestyle{empty}
}{\newpage}

\newcommand\@mydedication{\@latex@warning@no@line{No \noexpand\mydedication given}}
\newcommand*{\mydedication}[2]{\gdef\@mydedication{
    \hfill
    \parbox{.5\textwidth}{\Large\textit{
        #1\\
        #2
    }}
}}

\newcommand\makededication{\begin{mypagestyle}%
    \@mydedication
\end{mypagestyle}}
\makeatother

\mydedication{To my love}{For your patience and love.}
\mydedication{To God}{For all the good things he has given me.}

\begin{document}

\makededication

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Then you don't want to use `\gdef` but rather append to a command. Have a look at the `etoolbox` package.

Comment: You have a lot of spurious spaces in there, as well as `\it` is outdated

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I want to do this without any package.

Comment: If you want to do it without any packages, you can append stuff to a macro with `\xdef\@mydedication{\unexpanded\expandafter{\@mydedication<stuff you want to add>}}`.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments, they have been helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without packages, you can use `\g@addto@macro`:

```
\documentclass{book}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\joan@mydedication}{}
\newcommand{\joan@domydedication}[2]{%
   \parbox{.5\textwidth}{%
     \Large\itshape
     #1\\
     #2
   }%
   \par\addvspace{\bigskipamount}%
}
\newcommand*{\mydedication}[2]{%
  \g@addto@macro\joan@mydedication{\joan@domydedication{#1}{#2}}%
}

\newcommand\makededication{%
  \clearpage
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \begin{flushright}
  \vspace*{\stretch{0.3}}
  \ifx\joan@mydedication\@empty
    \@latex@warning@no@line{No \protect\mydedication\space given}%
  \else
    \joan@mydedication
  \fi
  \end{flushright}
  \vfill
  \clearpage
}
\makeatother

\mydedication{To my love}{For your patience and love.}
\mydedication{To God}{For all the good things he has given me.}

\begin{document}

\makededication

\end{document}
```

I added some vertical space at the top and some between dedications. You can customize them to suit your preferences.

In my opinion it's better to use the indirect approach of adding just a few tokens to `\joan@mydedication`, because it makes the code cleaner.

I added prefixes, which is a good practice to avoid clashes between classes and packages.

Adding a default definition of `\joan@mydedication` to issue a warning is handy for things such as `\title` that should appear just once, with no concatenation like in the present case. Checking for emptiness at usage of `\makededication` is easier, here. Note `\newcommand*{\joan@mydedication}{}`, so the check against `\@empty` will work (it wouldn't with just `\newcommand`).

Comment: `\newcommand*{\@mydedication}{}` is the same that `\newcommand\@mydedication{\@latex@warning@no@line{No \noexpand\mydedication given}}`?

Comment: @Joan No. I used a different strategy. The default definition with a warning is good if you don't have to concatenate; it becomes difficult to manage in the present case.

Comment: Thank you, as always, your answer has been the best.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{letter}

\makeatletter

\newenvironment{mypagestyle}{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
}{\newpage}%

\newcommand\@mydedicationelement[2]{%
  \hbox{\parbox[t]{.45\textwidth}{%
    \noindent\Large\textit{#1\\#2}%
  }}\hfill%
}%

\newcommand*\@mydedication{}

\newcommand*{\mydedication}[2]{%
  \g@addto@macro{\@mydedication}{\@mydedicationelement{#1}{#2}}%
}

\newcommand\makededication{%
  \begin{mypagestyle}%
  \ifx\@mydedication\@empty
     \@latex@warning@no@line{No \noexpand\mydedication given}%
  \fi
  {%
    \lineskip=.1\textwidth
    \leavevmode
    \@mydedication
    \par
  }%
  \end{mypagestyle}%
}
\makeatother

\mydedication{To my love}{For your patience and love.}
\mydedication{To God}{For all the good things he has given me.}
\mydedication{To Monty Python}{For the song ``All Things Dull And Ugly''.}
\mydedication{To my love}{For your patience and love.}
\mydedication{To God}{For all the good things he has given me.}
\mydedication{To Monty Python}{For the song ``All Things Dull And Ugly''.}

\begin{document}

\makededication

\end{document}
```

[image]

I guessed that you wish two columns from the circumstance that the `\parboxes` in the example of your question have half the textwidth.

If you need different alignment of dedications, don't hesitate to specify your needs as precisely as possible. Doing so eases up developing a solution that suits your needs as good as possible.